# A local or global name can not be found error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple rock paper scissors game, and I get an error with in the line, guess = input. It says I need to define the function or variable before I use it in this way and I am unsure of how I can do that. This is using Python/JES programming

```
#import random module
import random

#main function
def main():
    #intro message
    print("Let's play 'Rock, Paper, Scissors'!")
    #call the user's guess function
    number = user_guess()
    #call the computer's number function
    num = computer_number()
    #call the results function
    results(num, number)

#computer_number function
def computer_number():
    #get a random number in the range of 1 through 3
    num = random.randrange(1,4)
    #if/elif statement
    if num == 1:
        print("Computer chooses rock")
    elif num == 2:
        print("Computer chooses paper")
    elif num == 3:
        print("Computer chooses scissors")
    #return the number
    return num

#user_guess function
def user_guess(): 
    guess = input ("Choose 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' by typing that word. ")
    #while guess == 'paper' or guess == 'rock' or guess == 'scissors':
    if is_valid_guess(guess):
        #if/elif statement
        #assign 1 to rock
        if guess == 'rock':
            number = 1
        #assign 2 to paper
        elif guess == 'paper':
            number = 2
        #assign 3 to scissors
        elif guess == 'scissors':
            number = 3
        return number
    else:
        print('That response is invalid.')
        return user_guess()

def is_valid_guess(guess):
   if guess == 'rock' or guess == 'paper' or guess == 'scissors':
        status = True
   else:
        status = False
   return status

def restart():
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? Enter 'y' for yes or \
    'n' for no: ")
    #if/elif statement
    if answer == 'y':
        main()
    elif answer == 'n':
        print("Goodbye!")
    else:
        print("Please enter only 'y' or 'n'!")
        #call restart
        restart()

#results function
def results(num, number):
    #find the difference in the two numbers
    difference = num - number
    #if/elif statement
    if difference == 0:
        print("TIE!")
        #call restart
        restart()
    elif difference % 3 == 1:
        print("I'm sorry! You lost :(")
        #call restart
        restart()
    elif difference % 3 == 2:
        print("Congratulations! You won :)")
        #call restart
        restart()

main()
```

Comment: This rock paper scissors whatever deserves a new tag.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `input` is available on Python 3.x. On Python 2.x, it should be `raw_input`.

Comment: @devnull: please, lets not. Noone would follow the tag, the problems are far from specific to the game.

Comment: @MartijnPieters devnull seems to do the contest "most funny comments in Python section" this morning :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh no, I wasn't about to create one neither do I expect one to be created.  (Although, if one such tag existed, then it could be ignored.)

Comment: @devnull: besides, I'd totally make it a synonym of `rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock`...

Answer (score 0):

Using raw_input instead of input seems to solve the problem.

```
guess = raw_input ("Choose 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' by typing that word. ")
```

and also in

```
answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: ")
```

I'm using Python 2.7.x